# does any one have good and clear demo about Calabash(Android)?

Tags: automated-tests, calabash

I am learning Calabash
My question:- does any one have good and clear demo about Calabash(Android)?

Answer (score 0):

Try This one..
This project is intended to help you verify your Calabash-Android installation on a very simple apk.

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android-demoapp

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of articles and tutorials around:

- good overview of calabash android basics: http://www.dary.de/2012/04/calabash-android/
- the official calabash project has some documentation: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android
- article about the query syntax: http://krazyrobot.com/2014/04/calabash-using-query/